# How to show only one v-menu at a time when clicking to show the menu

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've ran the v-for loop on v-menu and I am trying to open the v-menu with only using the button.

The thing I am trying to accomplish is that I wanna open one menu at a time when clicking the button. Currently, it's showing every button and I believe because the v-menu itself's v-model is bind to a value so every v-menu that loops is looking at the value and when the value changes the entire v-menu shows up.

https://codepen.io/esphoenixc/pen/ExEMOYE

Here's my copepen and below is my code

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center d-flex align-center justify-space-around mt-16">
      <v-menu :open-on-hover="true" :open-on-click="true" v-for="user in userInfo" nudge-top="50px" v-model="show" top>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-avatar v-on="on" size="24" color="blue">
            <span>{{user.name}}</span>
          </v-avatar>
        </template>

        <span>{{user.favoriteFood}}<span>
      </v-menu>

      <v-btn @click="showTooltip">Button</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      userInfo: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "a",
          favoriteFood: "hamburger"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "b",
          favoriteFood: "spaghetti"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "c",
          favoriteFood: "Pasta"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "d",
          favoriteFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "e",
          favoriteFood: "BBQ"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "f",
          favoriteFood: "Philly Cheese Steak"
        }
      ],
      show: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    showTooltip() {
      console.log("Open tooltip");
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
});


So how can I only show one v-menu at a time when the button is clicked? I feel like I need to do something with the id values that's given but I can't seem to figure out the syntax or how to approach to solve the issue.
```

Comment: What you want is not clear for me. You have one button and said that ```open one menu at a time```. Which one do you want to open? Is there any condition that defines which one must be opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Observation :*** You are binding same boolean value for all the v-menu `model` which results updating `this.show` is impacting all the v-menu.

***Workaround :*** Assign show property in each menu object. So that it will work separately for each `v-menu`

```
mounted() {
  this.userInfo = this.userInfo.map(obj => {
    obj.show = false;
    return obj;
  });
}
```

In that case, Your template `v-model` will be : `v-model="user.show"`